# Wordpress + multilingual plugin (qtranslate) will not show the translation when switching languages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, translation

the problem I have with the multilingual plugin (qTranslate), is that it won't switch to another language it gives me 404 when trying to switch the language of posts.

This can be a result of either:

```
* WordPress is installed in a directory (not root) and you're using default links.
* URL rewriting is not enabled in your web server.
* The web server cannot write to the .htaccess file
```

I have my htaccess file with 644 and the following code is in there:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And I'm using a custom permalinks structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`

but I still have 404 when trying to switch language.
anybody knows what else could be adffecting the translation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this can help, but i had a kind of similar issue, only with the search results. with method get it was working fine for the main language, but english made 404, with method post for english, and german went to the home-page.

then i changed the url in the wp general settings from abc.com/def to abc.com (i had the directory in both fields and removed it from both). wp is not in www, but www-directory is redirected to the wp-folder. so the subdir was not necessary anymore (had it put for development). and, don't know why, but after this, the post method-search worked well like described in the wp-forum ( http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/ ) where you can find lots of useful tips for qtranslate issues. also applying the gettext might help: http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=294&sid=5be0c994e226ab99b5bed7c28a250bab

hope this helps.